# Return Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> from EF Core query without await?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I like to be as specific as is possible with my types.  When offering up a method encapsulating a query it's common to see `List<T>` returned (or more specifically `Task<List<T>>`.)  No wonder with EF Core's `.ToListAsync()` method.  But that's not very accurate is it?  `List<T>` is a projection of a larger collection in SQL Server (or whatever persistence you're using).  It's not modifiable.

I want to instead return `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` from my methods.  This seems a lot more accurate.  I'm returning a projection from my source data and you can't modify the source data by modifying the projection.  Nor can my result be modified erroneously without casting back to `List<T>` at which point you've gone far enough out of your way I'm assuming you know what you're doing.

So I attempted to just return the interface like I would synchronously.

```
public Task<IReadOnlyCollection<TResult>> GetResultAsync() =>
  _dbContext.Where(x => x.Property == true).ToListAsync();
```

I'm avoiding using the `async` and `await` operators here.  I want to pass the Task unawaited to avoid the `await` overhead.  But when wrapped in `Task<T>` C#'s type system doesn't recognize that the wrapped `List<T>` is castable to `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.  So `Task<List<T>>` cannot be cast to `Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>>`.  You can try an explicit cast, of course, but the compiler won't like that either and for the same reasons.

Well that's annoying.  But we can peel off the `Task<T>` with `async wait` easy enough.

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<TResult>> GetResultAsync() =>
  await _dbContext.Where(x => x.Property = true).ToListAsync();
```

In order to avoid the added code I considered an extension method.

```
public static async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> ToReadOnlyCollectionAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) =>
  await query.ToListAsync();
```

This gets the `await` out of my methods but of course still adds another await.  Is there a way to return `Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>>` for "free" from EF Core 2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea what `ToListAsync()` does but going by the name, and if I'm guessing correctly, it iterates the results and converts them to a list on a background thread and returns the task that must be `awaited` before the list is produced.

If that's the case, your question is

> how to convert `Task<List<T>>` to `Task<IReadonlyCollection<T>>`.

If so, you could in theory do something like this:

```
    public Task<IReadOnlyCollection<string>> ToReadOnlyCollection()
    {
        return ToListAsync().ContinueWith(x => new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(x.Result) as IReadOnlyCollection<string>);
    }

    public Task<IReadOnlyList<string>> ToReadOnlyList()
    {
        // if you don't mind an IReadOnlyList, you can use this
        // one which doesn't involve creating a new collection
        return ToListAsync().ContinueWith(x => x.Result as IReadOnlyList<string>);
    }

    private Task<List<string>> ToListAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(1000);
            return new List<string>
            {
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
            };
        });
    }
```

I don't believe `Task<T>` allows contra-variance so a `Task<TChild>` (where Child : Parent) cannot be automatically converted to `Task<TParent>` so you'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: I marked this as the answer but wanted to quickly answer your question.  `.ToListAsync()` from Entity Framework: queries the SQL database, deserializes the result, and returns the projection as a `List<T>` containing all the deserialized objects.

Comment: Additionally I would like to note `as` is probably the wrong operator here.  `As` implies the result may not be of type `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and if it's not, that's fine, just return null.  This is incorrect.  If the result of `ToListAsync<T>` isn't `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` then we should `throw` as something has gone very wrong or our underlying framework has changed and our code will need to be updated.  A regular old cast should be used here to get that effect.

Comment: @Licht Thank you for correcting me regarding `ToListAsync()`. It's been quite a long time since I worked with `EF` and I don't recall ever seeing that method. With regards to `as`, I imagined that the return type was of type `List<T>`. `List<T>` implements the `IReadOnlyList<T>` so the case is always valid. The `IReadOnlyCollection` is also always valid because we're first creating a `ReadOnlyCollection` (`new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(originalList`) and then "casting" it to an `IReadOnlyCollection`. It was all typed pretty quickly though so there may be an error here or there. Was more...

Comment: mean to convey the idea than an actual (and perfect) implementation.

Comment: I'd overlook it for exactly the reason you provided (the idea is more important than the exact implementation.) However, people have a tendency to copy paste from Stack Overflow.  So I think it's important to have implementations be as correct as possible since the code we write here can slip into code bases we aren't even aware of.  Maybe even a code base we then use some day.